# Tensorflow preprocessing as input to Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've trained a Keras model with `tf.data.Dataset` for input preprocessing.

Now I'm trying to use that model for inference, in another python script. I can't figure out how can I use Tensorflow preprocessing as input to a keras model.

In Tensorflow 2.0 this is very easy and works like this:

```py
model = MobileNetV2(
    input_shape=(68, 96, 1), alpha=1.0, include_top=True,
    weights=None, classes=3)
model.load_weights(...)

@tf.function
def predict(data):
    y_pred = model(preprocess_fn(data))
    return y_pred
```

But in TF 1.14 I can't made it work.
I've tried to build a model like this

```py
    input_sound = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(window_size,))
    net_input = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(preprocess_fn)(input_sound)
    model = MobileNetV2(
        input_shape=(68, 96, 1), alpha=1.0, include_top=True,
        weights=None, classes=3)
    model.load_weights(args.model)
    model = tf.keras.Model(input_sound, model(net_input))
```

And use it for inference like this:

```py
    with tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
            y_pred = sess.run(model(data))
```

This version works for a few steps (and then fails) and it's very slow (2+ seconds for a inference that should take 5 msec).

Another version:

```py
    with tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
            y_pred = model.predict(data)
```

This fails saying input to a model has shape `(1,)`. But it's not. Input sound has shape `(30700,)`, like it should have.

My preprocessing function looks like this:

```py
def preprocess_fn(sound):
    spectrogram = sound_to_log_mel(sound)
    spectrogram = tf.expand_dims(spectrogram, -1)  # (96, 68)->(96, 68, 1)
    spectrogram = tf.expand_dims(spectrogram, 0)  # (96, 68, 1)->(1, 96, 68, 1)
    spectrogram = tf.reshape(spectrogram, (1, 68, 96, 1))
    return spectrogram
```

Where `sound_to_log_mel` is a function that uses different Tensorflow operations.